# Cannot rename column after GroupBy

Tags: python, pandas

I am doing the following:

```
# Load date
data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/user/Desktop/STOCKS.txt', keep_default_na=True, sep='\t', nrows=5)

# Convert dates from object columns to datetime columns
data['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(data_orders['DATE'])

print(data.columns)
# Index(['COUNTRY_ID', 'STOCK_ID', 'DATE', 'STOCK_VALUE'], dtype='object')

# Count of stock per country per day
data_agg= data.groupby(['COUNTRY_ID'], as_index=False).agg({'DATE': 'count'})

print(data_agg.columns)
# Index(['COUNTRY_ID', 'DATE'], dtype='object')

# Rename count column
data_agg.rename({'DATE': 'Count'}, inplace=True)

print(data_agg.columns)
# Index(['COUNTRY_ID', 'DATE'], dtype='object')
```

As you see above at the last lines, I try to rename the aggregated column after the groupby but for some reason this does not work (I still get the name `DATE` for this column instead of `Count`).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Need `columns` keyword, if omit it, `rename` try change values of index:

```
data_agg.rename(columns={'DATE': 'Count'}, inplace=True)
```

---

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=10)
data = pd.DataFrame({'DATE': rng, 'COUNTRY_ID': [3]*3+ [4]*5 + [1]*2})  
print (data)
        DATE  COUNTRY_ID
0 2017-04-03           3
1 2017-04-04           3
2 2017-04-05           3
3 2017-04-06           4
4 2017-04-07           4
5 2017-04-08           4
6 2017-04-09           4
7 2017-04-10           4
8 2017-04-11           1
9 2017-04-12           1

data_agg= data.groupby(['COUNTRY_ID'], as_index=False).agg({'DATE': 'count'})
```

---

```
data_agg.rename({'DATE': 'Count', 1:'aaa'}, inplace=True)
print (data_agg)
     COUNTRY_ID  DATE
0             1     2
aaa           3     3
2             4     5
```

---

```
data_agg.rename(columns={'DATE': 'Count', 1:'aaa'}, inplace=True)
print (data_agg)
   COUNTRY_ID  Count
0           1      2
1           3      3
2           4      5
```

---

Another solution is remove `as_index=False` and use [`DataFrameGroupBy.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.count.html) with [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) with :

```
data_agg= data.groupby('COUNTRY_ID')['DATE'].count().reset_index(name='Count')

print (data_agg)
   COUNTRY_ID  Count
0           1      2
1           3      3
2           4      5
```

Comment: Yes, that's it thanks (upvote). I did not notice this detail.I had to specify the parameter `columns` when using this.

Comment: Ah ! Didn't see the `asindex=False`. wp

Answer (score 1):

I thinks this solves your problem

```
data_agg=data_agg.rename(columns={'Date':'Count'})
```